# Efficient factory functions without pointers (including smart pointers) or copies?

Tags: c++, performance, factory

Suppose I have some kind of factory function which creates objects that are largely used for a very short timespan only (possibly just for the duration of the scope of the function where this factory function is called).

Like this:

```
foo factory(some_parameter fancy_parameter)
{
   return foo(fancy_parameter);
}

//this gets called all the time... very often
void every_frame_function()
{
   for(int i=0; i<big_number; ++i)
       do_something_with(factory(some_parameter(i));

} //don't need those foos out here!
```

Is there a way to implement such factories without having the user care about memory management (by returning a pointer), without having to deal with smartpointer overhead and without returning a foo object that has to be hardcopied?

Maybe I'm asking for a goose that lays golden eggs here, but maybe there are some move semantics to be used here (I just don't know how).

Comment: Do you really want to create a new factory each time you call factory()? Or would returning the same factory each time work? Also whats the problem with smart pointers? They are the basis around which modern C++ works.

Comment: what is the problem the factory function appears to solve?

Comment: For (2D-)collision detection I need bounding boxes, which contain 13 2-dimensional vectors (4 corner vertices, 4 edge vertices, 4 normal vertices and one center vertex, all together 26 floats). The factory functions are there to create bounding boxes of certain types. Most of these bounding boxes are kept forever; However, I also have a lot of objects which are created on the fly, and I need to create bounding boxes for each of them. This is not a performance-killer and I'm not a fan of premature optimization, but I asked in case there is something that is easy to implement without hacking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::unique_ptr<T>`, it has zero overhead compared with a raw pointer.

Or simply return by value, but then you cannot do subtype polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will in many cases optimize out the copy, depending on what you do with it. For example:

```
type create();
void test {
   type local = create();       // Copy will be elided
   type const & ref = create(); // Extra copy will be elided
   local = create();
}
```

This is assuming that `create` is implemented in a way that (N)RVO can be applied, or else there would be another internal copy *before* returning from `create`.

Now, what is interesting is determining whether this is the correct approach or not which we cannot do since you are not providing enough information about the problem. For example, how costly are the objects returned by the factory to create, whether they hold resources, or whether you could reuse the object...

Comment: By weary of slicing of derived factories.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a problem about the deep copy and the shallow copy. Pointers are similar to a shallow copy.

Details for the two copies: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#In_C.2B.2B

Without using pointers in another function, you have to use the deep copy in your code. If the object is very big, deep copy will cost a lot of time, cause the program very slow. In your example about 2-dimensional vectors, the difference between the two copies is not obvious. But if the object is as large as a complicated dialog, the effect is very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't do it with a factory function, but you can do it with a class:

```
class Factory {
public:
   Base &create_obj(some_param p)
   {
      d.p =p;
      return d;
   }
 private:
   Derived d;
};
void every_frame_function() {
   Factory f;
   for(int i=0;i<bignumber;i++)
     {
     do_something_with(f.create_obj(some_parameter(i)));
     }
}
```